# A physical Accelerometer exists but virtual Significant Motion Sensor doesn't exist

Tags: android, android-sensors, pedometer, significant-motion-sensor

I have an Xperia Z phone which runs Android 5.1 on.

When checking the sensors that are present I get the below results:

```
mSensorAccelerometer: {Sensor name="MPL Accelerometer", vendor="Invensense", version=1, type=1, maxRange=19.6133, resolution=0.038344003, power=0.139, minDelay=5000}
mSensorLinearAcceleration: {Sensor name="MPL Linear Acceleration", vendor="Invensense", version=1, type=10, maxRange=19.6133, resolution=0.038344003, power=16.239, minDelay=5000}

mSensorSignificantMotion: null
mSensorStepDetector: null
mSensorStepCounter: null
```

So, there are a physical `Accelerometer` and a `Linear Acceleration` composite sensors.

Signification Sensor, Step Detector and Step Counter composite sensors seem as not present. However [the documentation](https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/sensor-types#significant_motion) writes that `Underlying physical sensor: Accelerometer` for these three sensors.

Is there any chance to use these three sensors?

Why do they seem as `null` although they are software-based (virtual) sensors?

Comment: Linear acceleration is derived from the accelerometer, but also uses the gyroscope to negate the effects of the earth’s gravitational field on the sensor. There is no physical sensor in your device that is called "linear acceleration." The linear accelerometer is a virtual sensor.

Comment: SensorStepDetector, and SensorStepCounter are also virtual sensors. This sensors require special hardware that was generally not available until around the time Android 4.4 was released. The problem is that probably your Xperia Z phone lacks the hardware that this virtual sensors use for constantly running in the background.